# Issue to start apache2 and SSH together during starting a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have installed Apache2 and openssh in ubuntu 18.4. image.
when i try to restart apache2 ill receive:

```
 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 99: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Setting ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.
```

but apache work proparly.
besides, My ssh also working well.

the problem is ,i want to automatically start these 2 both services during running container.
these are my try.

1- i try with dockerfile :

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

or reverse order.

2- i try to run during command line

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start &&  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
or
/etc/init.d/ssh start ;  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
or
/etc/init.d/ssh start &  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

3- i generate a bash script and run the bash script
and none of above are working.

does anyone have idea how can i solve it ?
ill be appreciate if have solution for apache error in container aswell.

thanks.

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null` is discouraged, it will make you container like doing nothing, better to change `service apache2 start` to `apachectl -D FOREGROUND` to this.

Comment: Typically Docker containers don't run ssh daemons.  It breaks the one-process-per-container guideline, managing credentials securely is extremely difficult, and it's unnecessary.  Just make the `CMD` be starting Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create `sctipt.sh` and copy it to the container using `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY script.sh script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
CMD ["./script.sh"]
```

script.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
service ssh start
service apache2 start
tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: " tail -f /dev/null  " this is great idea, to forcing remove notice/error, i just added it in my bash script and it works great .seems container try to restart when receive any notice or error.
Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an '&' after the first command.

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
(install ssh)
```

Then your entrypoint is the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec service ssh start &
exec apache2-foreground
```